# Flat table of data with folder name as a column

Tags: website-design, data-tables

We are currently building a flat table of documents whereby one of the columns is the parent folder of the document (a sortable and filter column to replace the categorised view)

What is the acceptable value to put in this column for documents that are on the root of the structure and therefore NOT in a folder? Should it be left blank, contain a dash, contain text such as "no folder" or "N/A"

Many thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to **include something meaningful**. Possible options:

- *Empty*: the user might think something went wrong in that field, the folder name is not valid (invalid characters), didn't load correctly, etc.
- *Dash* or similar symbol: the user might think the actual name of the folder is a dash (which might even be possible?)
- ***"No folder", "No parent", "root folder" or similar***: This is explicit and leaves no doubt. Present it in a different way than common folders, with quotes for example.

Comment: "root folder" is an excellent idea and fits my needs perfectly. +1 for the notes on Empty - the absence of data definitely leads the user to think the column had not loaded correctly